# App that track amazon product price

Tags: c#, object-oriented, web-scraping

main.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JsonReadWrite st = new JsonReadWrite();
        if (File.Exists(@"H:\TrackAmazonProduct-master\TrackAmazonProduct-master\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\product.json"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Product file exist do you want to create new product File? [y/n]");
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey();

            if (cki.Key.ToString().ToLower().Equals("y"))
            {
                createNewJson(st);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            createNewJson(st);
        }

        object objJson=st.readFile();
        int productCount = ((ConsoleApplication1.RootObject)objJson).product.Count;
        string[] productName = new string[productCount];
        string[] productValue = new string[productCount];

        bool sendMail = false;

        for (int k=0;k<productCount; k++)
        {
            // string url = "https://www.amazon.in/GENERIC-Ultra-Mini-Bluetooth-Dongle-Adapter/dp/B0117H7GZ6/ref=sr_1_14?crid=36FN332QCAZBD&dchild=1&keywords=earphones+under+200+rupees&qid=1586759890&sprefix=earp%2Caps%2C346&sr=8-14";

            //string url = "https://www.amazon.in/iVoltaa-Micro-USB-Type-Adapter/dp/B075F927V2/ref=lp_1389401031_1_4?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1586778682&sr=1-4";

            string url = ((ConsoleApplication1.RootObject)objJson).product[k].url;

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            Task<string> html = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html.Result.ToString().Trim());

            string nodeProduct = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@id='productTitle']")[0].InnerText.ToString().Trim();

            decimal nodePrice = Decimal.Parse(Regex.Replace(htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']")[0].InnerText.ToString().Trim().Replace(" ", ""), @"\s+", String.Empty), NumberStyles.Currency);

            //Console.WriteLine("ProductName:" + nodeProduct + " Price: " + nodePrice);

            if (nodePrice <= int.Parse(((ConsoleApplication1.RootObject)objJson).product[k].value))
            {
                sendMail = true;
                productName[k] = nodeProduct;
                productValue[k] = nodePrice.ToString();
            }

        }

        if (sendMail==true)
        {
           SendMail(String.Join(", ", productName),String.Join(", ", productValue));
        }
    }

    public static void createNewJson(JsonReadWrite st)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the number of product you want to track");
        string numProduct = Console.ReadLine();       
        st.GenerateJson(int.Parse(numProduct));
    }
    public static void SendMail(string productName,string newProductPrice)
    {
        try
        {
            string body = "The Price of Products " + productName + " is " + newProductPrice;
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("emailaddress", "From Name");
            MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("emailaddress", "To Name");
            const string fromPassword = "emailpassword";
            const string subject = "Price Has Been Decreased of Product";


            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Mail has been send");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {             
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

JsonReadWrite.cs

```
        using Newtonsoft.Json;
        using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
        using System;
        using System.Collections;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConsoleApplication1
  {
   public class Product
   {
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    }

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Product> product { get; set; }
}
class JsonReadWrite
{
    public void GenerateJson(int numProduct)
    {
        List<Product> listProduct = new List<Product>();
        for (int i=0;i<numProduct;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the product url and min price.");
            string productUrl = Console.ReadLine();
            string productMin = Console.ReadLine();
            Product p1 = new Product();
            p1.url = productUrl;
            p1.value = productMin;
            listProduct.Add(p1);
        }

        RootObject rt = new RootObject();
        rt.product = listProduct;
        string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rt);  
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"H:\TrackAmazonProduct-master\TrackAmazonProduct-master\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\product.json", strJson);      
    }    




    public object readFile()
    {
        string jsonStr = File.ReadAllText(@"H:\TrackAmazonProduct-master\TrackAmazonProduct-master\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\product.json");
        RootObject objJson= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonStr);
        return objJson;
    }
}
}
```

product.json

```
{
  "product":[
   {
     "url":"https://www.amazon.in/GENERIC-Ultra-Mini-Bluetooth- 
       Dongle-Adapter/dp/B0117H7GZ6/ref=sr_1_14?crid=36FN332QCAZBD&dchild=1&keywords=earphones+under+200+rupees&qid=1586759890&sprefix=earp%2Caps%2C346&sr=8-14",
     "value":"179"
  },
  {
     "url":"https://www.amazon.in/iVoltaa-Micro-USB-Type-Adapter/dp/B075F927V2/ref=lp_1389401031_1_4?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1586778682&sr=1-4",
     "value":"229"
  }
 ]
 }
```

I have made an app that tracks the product price and send mail when the product price decreases or is equal to the minimum price set by user.can someone specify improvement in my code.